# MultiThread in Android for Loop and Delay

Tags: android, multithreading

As you can see, I have to do TASK1 and continually TASK2. Between 1 and 2, they have delay. And then I want to repeat it infinitely till activity will be finished.

I have no experience for thread.. I can't fix this error.
Help ME!

```
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
          //TASK 1
          main_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          main_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          main_1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));


                Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    //TASK 2
                    main_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    main_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    main_2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));

                    }
                }, 1000);
                }
            }, 1000, 1000);
```

And it's my error

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for AsyncTask

Comment: So you mean I can solve this with AsyncTask??

Comment: Try my code. Just because what the errorlog says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer runs on **background thread**. You can not update `ui` from background thread, so always use `runOnUiThread` for that purpose.

```
  Timer timer = new Timer();
  timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
            YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                    main_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    main_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);              
                    main_1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
               }
            });

            Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                //TASK 2
                main_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                main_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                main_2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));

                }
            }, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { 

          @Override 
          public void run() { 
          //TASK 1 


         YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
 main_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          main_2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          main_1.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
            }
        });

                Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override 
                    public void run() { 
                    //TASK 2 
        YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                  main_1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    main_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    main_2.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
            }
        });


                    } 
                }, 1000); 
                } 
            }, 1000, 1000);
```